# The Relationship Between Cyclotomic Polynomials and Ramification

Tags: galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields, ramification

I am thinking about why the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n = \prod_{i \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^\times} (x - \zeta^i)$ is irreducible, where $\zeta$ is the $n$th root of unity over $\mathbb{Q}$. Specifically, I am trying to figure out how it is related to ramification and lifting the Frobenius element.

Let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$. $f(x) | \Phi_{n}(x)$, and we want to show that we have an equality. It suffices to show that, for any root $\zeta$ of $f(x)$, $\zeta^p$ is a root of $f(x)$. Take a prime $p$ relatively prime to $n$, and a primitive root of unity $\zeta$ which is a root of $f(x)$.

Write $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$. Write $p \mathcal{O}_K = \prod_{i = 1}^n \mathfrak{q}_i^{e_i}$, where $e_i$ are the ramification indices. Write $f_i = [\mathcal{O}_K / \mathfrak{q}_i: \mathbb{F}_p]$. The automorphism $\sigma \in \text{Aut}_{\mathbb{Q}}(K)$ sending $\zeta$ to $\zeta^p$ is a lift for the Frobenius element in $\text{Aut}_{\mathbb{F}_p}(\mathcal{O}_K / \mathfrak{q}_i)$. It is also the unique one. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399802/frobenius-element-in-cyclotomic-extension).

Can someone explain the below paragraph in terms of ramification and lifting factorizations? The proof is standard as it is though.

$\sigma(\zeta) = \zeta^p$ is a root of $x^n - 1$. Write $x^n - 1= f(x) g(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. If $\zeta^p$ is a root of $g(x)$, then $g(x^p)$ has $f(x)$ as a factor, i.e. $g(x^p) = f(x) h(x)$. In $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, we get $g(x)^p = f(x) h(x)$. This shows that $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ have a common factor in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, so that $x^n - 1$ has a multiple root in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, whereas it is separable by the standard derivation test.

I think something is going on in this last paragraph in terms of lifts of frobenius maps and ramification at $p$. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: For any $p \nmid n$, let $\mu$ be a primitive $n$-root of unity in $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$. There exists an homomorphism $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta] \to \Bbb{F}_p[\mu]$ sending $\zeta\to\mu$,, so $f(x) = \prod_{j=1}^J (x-\zeta^{a_j}) \in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ implies $f(x) = \prod_{j=1}^J (x-\mu^{a_j}) \in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$, and $f(\mu)^p = f(\mu^p) = 0$ implies one of the $\zeta^{a_j}$ is $\zeta^p$.

Comment: For the ramified case $p | n$ see [thisone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3197201/inertia-and-decomposition-field-in-mathbbq-omega-exp2-pi-i-m-where-m-p/3197738#3197738)

Comment: Thanks. If you leave this as an answer I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: Another [closely related thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1810787/11619).